# How can I use async in a named constructor?

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a class, and I want to use async in a named constructor or a method in the class that is accessible outside the class.  When making the named constructer return a `Future` type, I get an error saying: `Constructors can't have a return type`.

I then tried removing the `Future` type, and I still get an error saying `The modifier 'async' can't be applied to the body of a constructor`.

How can I use async in a named constructor?

```
class HttpService {
  Future<void> HttpService.getAll() async {
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull('http://localhost:4000/'),
      headers: {'headers': 'application/json'},
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {}
  }
}
```

I am new to oop, so I may be using it wrong? Any guidance is accepted.

Comment: Dont use async to constructors, create a separate method for that and invoke it in constructor.

Comment: How would I be able to invoke in in the constructor asynchronously? Would I just call it in the constructor, then when I call the class, I should add the `await` there?

Comment: @Blasanka  Also, is this best practice?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) If you want to implement your own method. `await Dio().get("http://www.google.com");` call async method after instancing is the right way to do so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Constructors can't be asynchronous.  If you find yourself wanting an asynchronous constructor, you instead could make a `static` asynchronous method that acts like an asynchronous factory.  From the perspective of the caller, [there isn't much difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54997386/179715) (and what differences there are mostly favor having a `static` method).  You additionally could make all other [constructors (including the default constructor) private](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57816373/179715) to force callers to use the `static` method to get an instance of your class.

That said, in *your* case, you might not even need a class at all.  Do you intend to have other methods on an `HttpService`?  Is your `HttpService` maintaining any internal state?  If not, then you would be better off with a freestanding function.

Comment: It will have other methods, but it will not retain any internal state. I am new to oop, and thought that it would be a good idea to create a class in order to combine all the http related methods. What is best practice?

Comment: @Jessica In general, different approaches will be better for different situations.  If you want to just group a bunch of functions together, [group them together in a library, not in a class](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-defining-a-class-that-contains-only-static-members).

Answer (score 7):

You can't use `async` in constructor. You should create a separate method for this.

**Solution: 1 (Recommended)**

```
class Foo {
  static Future<void> fetch() async { // method
    await future();
  }
}
```

---

**Solution: 2**

```
class Foo {
  Foo.named() { // named constructor
    future().then((_) {
      // future is completed do whatever you need
    });
  }
}
```