# How to recreate singleton instance if different params are passed to the constructor in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, singleton

I gathered the following understanding for creating a singleton in dart with params

```
class Foo extends ChangeNotifier {
  late String channel;

  void instanceMemberFunction () {
      print('Foo created with channel $channel')
  }

  static final Foo _instance = Foo._internal();

  Foo._internal() {
    instanceMemberFunction();
  }

  factory Foo({
    required String channel
  }) {
    _instance.channel = channel;
    return _instance;
  }
}
```

and I am calling the instance like so

```
Foo({channel: "bar"})
```

Now I want to have some working that if I use

```
Foo({channel: "baz"})
```

Then a new instance is created and it's okay in that case to destroy the old one. How can I achieve this in dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you've copied some existing example for creating a singleton without fully understanding what it's doing and why.  The core parts are:

1. The single instance is stored in a global or `static` variable.
2. The class has one or more public `factory` constructors that returns that global/`static` variable, initializing it if necessary.
3. All other constructors for the class are private to force consumers to go through the `factory` constructors.

Therefore, if you want your `factory` constructor to replace its singleton based on its argument, you need to:

1. Make your `factory` constructor check if the argument is appropriate for the existing instance.  If it is, return the existing instance.  If not (or if there is no existing instance), create and return a new instance.
2. Since you need to check if the existing instance is initialized, make it nullable. (You alternatively could initialize it to a non-null sentinel value, e.g. `Foo._internal(channel: '')`.
3. Pass the argument along to the private constructor.

```dart
class Foo extends ChangeNotifier {
  final String channel;

  void instanceMemberFunction () {
    print('Foo created with channel $channel');
  }

  static Foo? _instance;

  Foo._internal({required this.channel}) {
    instanceMemberFunction();
  }

  factory Foo({required String channel}) {
    if (channel != _instance?.channel) {
      _instance = Foo._internal(channel: channel);
    }
    return _instance!;
  }
}
```

Note that this implementation will create a *new* object if the constructor argument changes, which isn't very singleton-like.  Depending on what you want to do, you could:

- Return a new object (which could allow multiple simultaneous instances).
- Return the existing object.
- Return the existing object, but mutate it with the constructor argument.